# Is it possible to make covenant city a settlement by capturing it forcefully?

Tags: fallout-4

I discovered covenant city but no quest related to it yet. Is it possible to kill all the inhabitants and make it one of my settlements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to technically settle this place.  You will have to complete the [Human Error Quest](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Human_Error) and kill everyone but Deezer and the house cat **or** complete the quest via speech challenges if you can do so (however, this will leave everyone alive).

Here is what the [Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Covenant) states:

> **It is possible to settle in Covenant if the player character completes the Human Error side quest.** If the Sole Survivor sides against Covenant then returns after completion, it will initiate a battle with the residents and settlers, after which it is possible to use the workshop. In order to settle, everyone must be killed, except the house cat and Deezer. **If the Sole Survivor decides to side with Covenant and completes the quest with speech checks then the town will allow the Sole Survivor to join without any conflict**.

After doing either of these, you should be able to use the workbench at the settlement.

Comment: Should point out that there are various bugs associated with settling Covenant. I don't know if it *always* happens, but at least some of the time the things in the city are still marked as owned by the inhabitants, even if they are dead, so everything is stealing. Additionally, the turrets remain hostile to the player. I've settled this place, sent a settler there, and had them get in a fight with the turrets. The wiki page lists these things under the Bugs section.

Comment: @DCShannon t I remember in my game it acted odd as well with turrets and the items.  The turrets were hostile, but they wouldn't shoot at me and were indestructible.

Comment: I found covenant and followed along the quests but then decided I hated everyone there and massacred the whole town. It let me build like any other settlement except it didn't allow me to sleep in the nice, well kept beds. Had to build my nasty ones.

Comment: DeeZer can be destroyed and you still can take over covenant, the time I did it only the house cat remained alive